# Busquedas con varios campos sql server y c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo un `DataGridView` que se llena con una base de datos en `sql server`

Como pueda hacer una busqueda de varios campos segun el usuario lo decida

Por ejemplo que busque nombre, edad y traiga los datos que coincidan o nombre,edad y carrera segun el usuario lo decida

Como se hace esta busqueda con varios `textbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este articulo explico justamente esto que planteas

[Filtros Condicionales (1/2)](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2011/09/filtros-condicionales.html)

puedes hacer filtros condicionales segun se haya especificado el dato o no

```
string sql = @"SELECT *
               FROM Tabla T1
               WHERE ((@nombre IS NULL) OR (T1.Nombre LIKE '%' + @nombre + '%'))
                AND ((@edad IS NULL) OR (T1.Edad = @edad))
                AND ((@carrera IS NULL) OR (T1.Carrera = @carrera))";


using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNombre.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : txtNombre.Text);

    int edad = 0;
    int.TrayParse(txtEdad.Text, out edad);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edad", edad == 0 ? (object)DBNull.Value : edad);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carrera", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCarrera.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : txtCarrera.Text);

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    //resto codigo

}
```

como veras si el dato no se indica se envia un `DBNull.Value` para que luego en la query se pueda detectar y no aplicar ese filtro